# Should Docstring contain a 'Raises' statement if the error is handled in the code

Tags: python, docstring

Suppose I have a simple function. For example:

```py
def if_a_float(string):
   try:
       float(string)
   except ValueError:
       return False
   else:
       return True
```

Should I include the `Raises: ValueError` statement into my docstring or should I avoid it as the error was already handled in the code? Is it done for any error (caught/uncaught)? I do understand that it probably depends on the style, so let's say I am using the [Google Docstring style](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html,)(though I guess it doesn't matter that much)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should document the exception raised explicitly, as well as those that may be relevant to the interface, as per the [Google Style Guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#doc-function-raises) (the same document you mention yourself).

This code does not raise an exception explicitly (there is no `raise`), and you do not need to mention that you are catching one.
Actually, this code cannot even accidentally raise one (you are catching the only line that could) and therefore it would be misleading if you were to document that the `if_a_float()` was raising a `ValueError`.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to be 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

You should only document the exceptions that callers need to be aware of and may want to catch. If the function catches an exception itself and doesn't raise it to the caller, it's an internal implementation detail that callers don't need to be aware of, so it doesn't need to be documented.